# What exactly is this Shell Script doing?

Tags: programming

I want to know what this Shell Script does.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for i in $*
do
echo "cat>$i<<'end of $i'"
cat $i
echo "End of $i"
done
```

I mean, how is it working?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Script takes name of files as inputs and then print the content of those files in a format like this:

```
cat>FILE_NAME<<'end of FILE_NAME'
"Here goes the content"
End of FILE_NAME
```

To run this script

```
sh SCRIPT_NAME.sh fileA fileB fileC ....
```

The image illustrates more
[image]